# SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST for some host does not show `Client port`

Tags: mysql

I am executing `Show Full Processlist;` and output does not show `client port` for some hosts in `Host` column

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html) says that each and every connection has `host`:`client_port` format.

My question is for some of the host column it just shows `localhost` without client port

What could be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that it's not connected via TCP/IP, so there isn't a port.

MySQL allows local clients to connect via a "socket file", which is located on the file system (`/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`, for example`).

Comment: I will verify whether any connection is connected through socket

Comment: It's not through socket, it's using SSH connection (TCP connection)

Comment: It isn't possible to connect to MySQL "using SSH."  If you mean that you are are using SSH to log in to the machine where MySQL is running, and then typing "mysql" to interact with the server, the "mysql" command line *client* is the client -- not you, on the originating side of that SSH connection -- and the client is indeed connecting from "localhost" and most likely it will use the socket, not TCP... which causes the behavior you observed. @Phil is correct. +1

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine just found a bug where the client_port portion of this field is not populated on a 5.0 server if you start with --skip-grant-tables

You can see the host, but the port is not displayed.

Starting without that option restores the ability to see the port in this field.